# Unicode characters within text document display on browser

Tags: html, browser, unicode

I've created a very simple functional web page. I have the file index.html which 
has a link. A local link which points to a txt file inside the File manager of my
website.

I understand what the problem is. I just don't know how to fix it.

My text document has Unicode characters such as ± and √ and ² and ³.
These characters display well in the notepad file they were created in.

When the user clicks on the link it opens up this text file, which is not formatted in HTML, therefore, the Unicode characters don't appear on the 
browser.

I can either re-type this text document with HTML tags and use the special symbol
numeric codes within it and it will most likely work. And, that is something 
I don't want to go through.

Is there any other way to go around this problem. I need the browser to display
these characters within the text document.

Is there a way to tell the browser to convert the text document to HTML on the fly.

thanks

Comment: Can you please add the code you use for opening the txt file? And please add information of how the file opens - its downloade? its content is displayed? I just don't think the question is clear without this information.

Comment: Are you sure you saved data as Unicode? Which encoding of Unicode? AFAIK notepad will not save Unicode encodings by default. -- In general: try to use UTF-8 only workflow, and all because with less troubles (still troubles on building the steps, but you will find easily in which step you have problems).

Comment: You haven't said what the character encoding of the text file is and if there any constraints on changing it. There is no text but encoded text. Just having the bytes from the file is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-ASCII characters just fine.  If you save the file as UTF-8, every browser that’s been updated this century will be able to display it.  It’s been decades since browsers choked on a byte-order mark, but most people recommend leaving it out.

You can also use non-ASCII characters in HTML saved as UTF-8, literally and without any escape codes.  While browsers should be able to detect the character set, best practice is to add either the tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` immediately after the `<html>` tag.  This removes all ambiguity.